# Using COUNT result from a JOIN in a WHERE statement

Tags: count, where-clause

I am self teaching SQL both for pleasure and to switch career and so this query is quite basic but please bare with me...

I have this query which works fine...

```
SELECT m.MatchID, COUNT (p.MatchId) AS 'PlayerMatchAdded'
FROM Matches AS m
LEFT JOIN PlayerMatch AS p ON p.MatchID = m.MatchID
WHERE Season = '2020/2021'
GROUP BY m.MatchID
ORDER BY m.Month DESC, m.Date DESC;
```

I want to only show results where the COUNT result was 0.\

EDIT - a bit of further research leads me to understand I need to use HAVING instead of WHERE, any advice on how to rewrite this would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted....

```
SELECT Matches.MatchID, COUNT (PlayerMatch.MatchId)
FROM Matches
LEFT JOIN PlayerMatch ON PlayerMatch.MatchID = Matches.MatchID
GROUP BY Matches.MatchID
HAVING Season = '2020/2021' AND COUNT (PlayerMatch.MatchId) = 0
ORDER BY Matches.Month DESC, Matches.Date DESC;
```

Is there a better way to write this so I can avoid bad habits forming early?